# Looking for a book flip library/plugin

Tags: css, html, javascript

I'm looking for a "flip book" effect that works on Ipad, without Flash.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This website here gives a nice solution using jQuery. The code is shown in detail.
[Page flip jQuery Plugin](http://grasshopperpebbles.com/ajax/jquery-plugin-imbookflip-page-turning-without-flash/)
Examples would be [here](http://grasshopperpebbles.com/demos/index.php/bookflip/manual)
This as an alternative to the already give solution in case that you want to make a photo gallery or something similar. You would have to embed it a little nicer than in the examples though ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try http://www.paulbrunt.co.uk/svgflip/. Don't know if it works on ipad or not, but it's all open web tech (html,svg,css,ecmascript).

Answer (score 1):

with css3 http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/page-flip.html